# Updated Android SDK and Android Studio messed up all my XMLs: "Element XXX not allowed here"

Tags: android, xml

I just updated my Android Studio and Android SDK, and now I can't do anything in my XMLs. It shows the same thing as previous, but I can't add anything and something got messed up.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bocterAppLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/bocterapp"
        android:contentDescription=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It error says: "Element ImageView is not allowed here".

Do you have any idea why this has happened?

Cheers!

Comment: If you just updated your Android SDK, you must also update your Android Development Tools (ADT). Then, clean your project and try again after the udpate.

Comment: I have updated my "sdk tools" from SDK Manager and problem is solved.
I have also used "Invalidate caches and restart" option of File menu in Android studio.

Comment: the correcto solution is the @pathe.kiran suggestion. Invalidate caches and restar solve the problem for me. Thanks! Can you make an Answer with the solution?

Comment: I had the same problem but Android SDK update and "invalidate caches and restart" didn't help me. The only thing that worked was to reimport my project (via File->Open)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Try to exchange the ImageView with the     android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView! That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. In my case, I was using a container from the old support library. So changing

`<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ... />`

to

`<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ... />`

solved it for me - with no change to the ImageView.